# Trigger notification on Android device remotely

Tags: android, python, notifications

Is it possible to remotely trigger a notification to appear on my android device? 
My idea is to have a Python script ping me via a function, but I have not found a library that is able to do that.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: and something like https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM